# Popup widget after tab changing

Tags: javascript, browser, popup, dom-events

Is it possible to make popup form appear after change of browser tab (when visibilityState == 'hidden')? I mean something like video player in the Yandex browser...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `visibilitychange` event

```js
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", (event) => {
  if (document.visibilityState == "visible") {
    console.log("tab is active")
  } else {
    console.log("tab is inactive")
  }
})
```